# Solutions to a stochastic differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

$$dX_t = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-2X_t}\ \ dt+e^{-X_t}dB_t,
X_0=x_0$$

**Hint**: solve this equation using the substitution $X_t=u(B_t)$,
show that the solution blows up at a finite random time.

Comment: Can one have **less** input in a question?

Comment: I checked it again. It's the same as that on the exam paper.

Comment: So there **was** a hint, after all. By the way: what is blocking you here? What similar questions can you solve? What did you try? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I want to use Ito's lemma and then to apply the coefficient matching. But I get a strange result. I think there may be something wrong, so I just keep the oringinal problem here.

Comment: You might want to show your *strange result*.

Comment: OK. I add what I have done to the problem discreption.

Comment: Why $f(t)=1/(t-1)$?

Comment: Just solve the ODE $f'=-f^2$

Comment: Your $f$ is not the only solution of $f'=-f^2$, is it?

Comment: No. In fact this is another problem. I don't know how to get the analytical solution of the ODE $f'=f^2$.

Comment: I would say this is your **main** problem: to determine the solutions of the ODE $y'=-y^2$. Sure you cannot do this? Hint: the ODE means $-y'/y^2=1$.

Comment: $y(t)=\frac{1}{t+C}$？

Comment: Right. Now you have everything that is needed to complete the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I'm still confused about the meaning of "the solution blows up at a finite random time" mean? Does it mean that after finite random time, $B_t$   hits $−C$ , and $X_t$   goes to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X_t=u(B_t)$.

Using Ito's lemma,
$dX_t=u'dB_t+\frac{1}{2}u''dt$

By coefficient matching with the given fomula $dX_t=e^{-X_t}dB_t-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2X_t} dt$, we get $u'=e^{-u}, u''=-e^{-2u}$.

let $f=u'$, then $f^2=-f'$.

Solve above ODE, $f(t)=\frac{1}{t+C}$, C is constant.

$u'(t)=f(t)=\frac{1}{t+C}$
$\Rightarrow u(t)=\ln(t+C)$
$\Rightarrow X_t=u(B_t)=\ln(B_t+C)$

$X_0=x_0 \Rightarrow \ln(B_0+C)=x_0 \Rightarrow C=e^{x_0}$.

$C=e^{x_0}$ is bounded. After finite random time, $B_t$ hits $-e^{x_0}$ with probability one, and $X_t$ goes to $\infty$.